# Iterate over preprocessor defines and process them

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to build a macro

```
#define F(...) ???
```

which will expand the following construction

```
#define A 1
#define B 2
#define C 3
#define D 4
F(A, B, C, D)
```

into the following code:

```
1, "A", 2, "B", 3, "C", 4, "D"
```

I've tried to use Boost.Preprocessor, but it seems that it lacks desired functionality:

```
#define Q(r, data, elem) elem, BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(elem),
#define F(...) BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(Q,,BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__))
F(A, B, C, D)
```

expands to
1, "1", 2, "2", 3, "3", 4, "4" which is not what I want to achive. This happens inside BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ so I can't really control it.

Is there any easy way to do this without overloaded macros or with overloaded macros but in already existing lib?

EDIT:
I'm using C++ so both C and C++ solutions are fine

EDIT2:

This is a pure C++17 solution

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <array>
#include <string_view>

namespace detail {
    template <std::size_t N>
    constexpr auto split_args(std::string_view s) {
        std::array<std::string_view, N> arr{};

        std::size_t begin{ 0 }, end{ 0 };
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N && end != std::string_view::npos; ++i)
        {
            end = s.find_first_of(',', begin);
            arr[i] = s.substr(begin, end - begin);
            arr[i].remove_prefix(std::min(arr[i].find_first_not_of(' '), arr[i].size()));
            begin = end + 1;
        }

        return arr;
    }

    template <std::size_t N, int ...Values, std::size_t ...I>
    constexpr auto get_array(std::array<std::string_view, N> strings, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
        return std::array<std::pair<std::string_view, int>, N> { std::make_pair(strings[I], Values)... };
    }
}

#define EXPAND(x) x
#define VA_ARGS_SIZE(...) std::tuple_size<decltype(std::make_tuple(__VA_ARGS__))>::value
#define F(...) detail::get_array<VA_ARGS_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__>( detail::split_args<VA_ARGS_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__)>( EXPAND( #__VA_ARGS__ ) ), std::make_index_sequence<VA_ARGS_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__)>{} )

#define A 1
#define B 3
#define C 3
#define D 7

int main()
{
    constexpr auto x = F(A, B, C, D);
    for (const auto &c : x) {
        std::cout << c.first << " " << c.second << "\n";
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

output:

> A 1
>
> B 3
>
> C 3
>
> D 7

Thanks, @rici, for the idea!

Comment: as it's c++, have you considered constexpr?

Comment: You have tagged both [c] and [c++].  These are different languages.  For which one do you actually require a solution?  You have tagged [boost-preprocessor].  Do you actually need to use Boost (which, for one thing, implies C++)?

Comment: Is it required that `F` be a *variadic* macro?

Comment: @john: Using the Boost Preprocessor Library does not imply C++. "The Boost Preprocessing library is a library of macros, with support for preprocessor metaprogramming. **The library supports both C++ and C compilation.** It does not depend on any other Boost libraries and therefore may be used as a standalone library." (from [the docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html), emphasis added.)

Comment: @rici, thanks for pointing that

Comment: @John Bollinger, yes, it is required to be variadic. I actually need any implementation C or C++.

Comment: @Krzysztof Szewczyk, I need to get stringified name of the define (to the point they are in the 3rd party library). Therefore I use macro for "#" feature. I don't really like this, but it will save plenty of time for me

Comment: `I'm using C++ so both C and C++ solutions are fine` If you are using C++, that means you are not using C.

Comment: @KamilCuk, I believe any C solution is fine for C++ in this case. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments to `F` are being expanded immediately, before the preprocessor starts expanding the replacement list. So by the time `BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ` is invoked, the names of the parameters have been lost. That's not really a problem which can be solved by that library.

Immediate expansion of macro arguments can be suppressed by using either `#` or `##` in the replacement body. This applies as well to variadic arguments, so you could define, for example

```
#define F(...) INTERPOLATE(#__VA_ARGS__, __VA_ARGS__)
#define INTERPOLATE(names, ...) /* See below */
```

`INTERPOLATE` would then be invoked with arguments `"A, B, C, D", 1, 2, 3, 4`, and it would have to split its first argument and distribute it. That would be easy enough at run-time using, for example `strstr`, so if a run-time solution is acceptable, it's available. (You can use the BOOST_PP library to count the arguments and pass that number to a variadic run-time function, possibly simplifying the implementation.)

Splitting a string literal can be done at compile-time if you are using C++17, which has `constexpr` `std::stringview` member functions.
But there's no facility in C which can do that. (It's possible that you can convince a compiler to optimize the run-time code, though. Some experimentation would be necessary.)

If none of the above works for you, you could easily do a transformation on the source text with something as simple as a Python script which replaces the invocation of `F(A, B, C, D)` with something like:

```
F(("A", A), ("B", B), ("C", C), ("D", D))`
```

Comment: I don't really want to use scripts and also it became kind of a challenge for me :) I'm actually using C++ but since macro is C feature I tagged it as C also. I already achieved the construction which expands to `"A, B, C, D", 1, 2, 3, 4`, but the idea to further process it in compile time (runtime is really undesired) hadn't come into my mind! This is also probably possible with template deduction, but I'll check if I can upgrade my project to C++17 because working with `constexpr` indeed should be much easier. Thank you!

Comment: @espkk: if you are using C++, you should tag only as C++.  That makes life easier for people answering. You can also use the [tag:c-preprocessor] tag if relevant (despite its name, it applies to both the C and C++ preprocessors.)

Comment: (For example, if I'd known you were interested only in C++, I could have focused only on that solution, saving both of us time).